# Is it possible to serialize a C Structures (struct) to a JSON string (char*)

Tags: c, json

I want to do something like:

```
const int DEFAULT_INTDATA = 0;
const char DEFAULT_STRDATA[] = "default";

typedef struct
{
    int intdata;
    char * strdata;
} DATA;

DATA data;
data.intdata = DEFAULT_INTDATA;
data.strdata = DEFAULT_STRDATA;

// output JSON string of "data".
printf("%s", JSONstringify(data));
```

Comment: How well have you searched? First hit I got on Google was [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjson/). There are many more.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think OP wants a fully automatic universal solution, but why that's not possible in C is explained by cHao

Answer (score 3):

Not generically.  Standard C doesn't have the reflection capabilities required to get the names and types of data fields at runtime.

You could of course write a JSON serializer for a certain struct, but not one that'd take any and every struct and convert it to/from JSON.